# Methodless Abstract class?

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
    virtual void bePolymorphic() = 0; // Will never be used
};

class Derived : Base
{
    virtual void bePolymorphic() override {}; // I have to do this in every derived class
};
```

This is the hack that I have been using recently to make `Base` an abstract class if it doesn't have any member functions.

In Java there is an `abstract` keyword. Why isn't there one in C++? Is there another way of making a class abstract?

Comment: Have a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: @DeiDei Will I have to override it in every derived class?

Comment: No, you can't override destructors...

Comment: It's not necessary to explicitly override destructors.   The compiler generates destructors if they are not declared.

Comment: So, why does `Base` have to be "abstract" if it doesn't have any member functions?

Comment: @BoPersson So I can `dynamic_cast`; basically I want to have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` populated with derived classes

Comment: @kim666: Just curious, You populated that vector with Base typed pointers of Derived classes. What for ?

Comment: now I am also curious, why that wouldnt work with a simple `class Base{}` as base?

Comment: @kim366: You want to have an item_manager by storing Base pointers. You know you can not properly delete the object without dynamic_cast and is RTTI enabled ? Just add the virtual destructor to be safe...

Comment: @Malkocoglu Interesing. I never really used the destructor before. I updated it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic work-around to this problem<sup>*</sup> is to make destructor pure virtual. Of course you must implement it outside the class:

```
// In the header file
class Base {
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
// In the source file
Base::~Base() {
}
```

<sup>*</sup> This suggestion comes from one of [Scott Meyers](https://www.amazon.com/Scott-Meyers/e/B004BBEYYW/)' books.

Comment: What? Since when can you give an abstract function a body?

Comment: It Works, though

Comment: @kim366 Since forever.

Comment: @kim366 This is counterintuitive, but it has been allowed even before the first C++ standard of 1998 came out.

Comment: @molbdnilo Misspelled, sorry, meant function

Comment: Pity that `= default` can't be used in conjunction with `= 0` to avoid the empty destructor implementation.

Comment: How is it any different than writing virtual ~Base(){}; in the header ?

Comment: @Malkocoglu The main difference is that unless you put `=0`, users of your class would be able to instantiate it directly.

Comment: @kim366 that has always been possible and you can even call the implementation from derived classes. It can be handy as a way to say "you mist override this function (and can't directly instantiate this class) but I've provded a default implementation you can just call if you don't need anything more specific".

Comment: @Malkocoglu there is a subtle difference between `~Foo() = default;` and `~Foo() {}` - the first destructor is trivial, the second one is by definition *not trivial* since it has a user provided implementation (this is so, even if that implementation is empty).

Comment: @JesperJuhl But this only works with the virtual destructor or also with other functions?

Comment: @kim366 all member functions.

Comment: @kim366 no, it's just C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, it's features still surprise me! Lambdas blew my mind back in the day

Comment: Oh, but the definition of pure virtual method only works on the destructor? I tried it with oder methods and it doesn't work

Comment: @kim366 Providing definitions for member functions marked pure virtual works for all kinds of member functions, not only for destructors. However, these functions remain pure virtual, in the sense that deriving classes must override them. The difference is that derived classes can rely upon an implementation provided in the base class.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Can you implicitly override them? And how does the class rely on the other definition, if it is overridden?

Comment: @kim366 You cannot implicitly override pure virtual member functions. You can call functions from the base with member resolution operator, i.e. `MyBaseClass::myPureVirtual()`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ah, okay. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no abstract specifier in C++. The equivalent is to make your constructor protected:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
}
```

In addition, the C++ equivalent of a Java interface is one in which all of your methods are pure virtual, as you have, and the constructor is protected.
Also note that it's a good idea to always make the destructor virtual in a base class. If a derived class needs a destructor and the parent's destructor isn't virtual, the derived's constructor won't be called.

Comment: It is not possible to have a virtual constructor.   (There's a virtual constructor idiom, but that's something different than you have shown).

Comment: That's right. The constructor doesn't need to be virtual. Just the destructor.

Comment: A constructor CANNOT be virtual.   Feed your original (before you edited it) code sample with a virtual constructor to a compiler, and it won't compile.

Comment: I am aware. Just having a brain fart, apparently. Nonetheless, I appreciate you pointing that out for other readers.